# Disabling/Enabling div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am relatively new to jQuery. I am working on an application to create a widget for accepting donations for NGO.

```
<div data-rle="content" id="save">  
<label for="saveWidget">Save your Widget before posting in online:</label>  
<input type="submit" value="Save Widget" id="saveWidget"
data-theme="b" data-inline="true" />  
</div>  
<div data-rle="content" id="post">  
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">  
    <legend>Select on option for posting your online:</legend>  
    <input type="radio" name="submit" id="html" value="hmtl"
    checked="checked" /> <label for="html">Please provide
    the HTML - I'll post it myself. <br>The HTML will be
    displayed below.</label>   
            <input type="radio" name="submit" id="blog" value="blog" />   <label
    for="blog">Go to Blogger</label>  
</fieldset>  
<input type="submit" value="Get HTML" id="submitWidget"
data-theme="b" data-inline="true" />  
</div>
```

My goal is to have the div with `id="post"` disabled in the start, and when user clicks on save I want to enable the div. I tried using `$('#post').attr('disabled', true);` but it does not seem to work. The div does not get disabled
Any ideas on how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable a div"? A `div` is just a container.

Comment: One does not simply disable a `div`. You need to disable the `<input>` elements _inside_ the `div`.

Comment: Div elements have no intrinsic interaction so disabling one is meaningless (so they have no such attribute or property).

Comment: maybe you want to hide the div?

Comment: What I want to achieve is that the div is grayed out and on user clicking the save button, I would allow the user to interact with the div. I can also show/hide the div, but I want to know if there is any other way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MTQzD/?

When document is ready disable all inputs in `#post`. Also give  #post a color of your choice in your css (e.g. lightGray).
Then when "Save Widget" is clicked, enable the inputs and remove the color of the #post div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#submitWidget').attr('disabled', true);
});

$("#saveWidget").click(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#submitWidget').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#post').css("background-color", "#EAEAEA");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Works exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean disabling the inputs inside the div?
I'm not into jQuery, but I guess it should be like:  `$( "#div > input" ).attr( "disabled" , "true" );`.

Maybe without the `true` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

> Div

```
<span id="template_buttons">
  <button class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button">Button 3</button>
</span>
```

> For disable all objects

```
$("#template_buttons *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
```

> For Enable all objects

```
$("#template_buttons *").attr("disabled", false);
```

Check in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/muthupandiant/orv2d9k1/1/

Answer (score 0):

**$('#div_name :input').attr('disabled', true);** //disable div input elements

**$('#div_pjt :input').removeAttr('disabled');**// enable div input elements

> This code works for me

Comment: A little context would be nice.