# Disabling a div upon some event using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, image, javascript

I have an image

```
<div id="map-viewer-button"><img src="image/Btn1.png"
                    onmouseover="this.src='image/Btn2.png'"
                    onmouseout="this.src='image/Btn1.png'"
                    onmousedown="this.src='image/Btn3.png'"
                    onmouseup="this.src='image/Btn2.png'"               
                    onclick="disableButton()" width="200px" height="100px"></div>
```

I want to disable the image after it is being clicked. And enable it when some other condition occurs.

```
function disableButton(){
        $('#map-viewer-button :input').attr('disabled', true);
}
function enableButton(){
        $('#map-viewer-button :input').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

But this does not work. What could be the reason? Is there any other method to do so?

Comment: yes i see an <img>, but i dont see the button

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436468/disabling-enabling-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) attribute is for form controls

> The following elements support the disabled attribute: BUTTON, INPUT, OPTGROUP, OPTION, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

you can instead use an `<input type="image" />` element

to disable an image input inline use: `... onclick="this.disabled = true" />`

---

[demo jsfiddle (pure JavaScript)](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/NfDXu/1/)

[demo jsfiddle (jQuery)](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/d7hMU/1/)

Comment: When I use <input type="image" />, I am able to disable the image. But I want to execute a function and then disable the button upon click. I tried 
...onclick="execute();this.disabled=true;"
But it did not work. Later I will also want to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

please change the code to this and try...

```
function disableButton(){
        $('#map-viewer-button :img').attr('disabled', true);
}
function enableButton(){
        $('#map-viewer-button :img').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```